# Simple captcha form action validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, action, captcha

Hello I need a simple captcha validator in PHP form. I download a sample from the internet. 
the form name is:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >
```

The problem IS my form have an action action="form_processing.php" and I do not know what Should I Put in function validate()  to redirect the form to form_processing.php  . 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: And the submit is: `<input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="Submit" class="button1">`

Comment: Generally, you use an API for a captcha. Google provides a simple one.

Comment: I know, But I do not want to use Goodle Api. I would like to do it by php...

Comment: How secure does it need to be? You could randomly generate some string that the user has to copy on input, but you would need to store it with session or cookie to validate it